# Reading lines from a file and storing their content to pass to a C program in a shell script

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a C program and the inputs are given through command line. Now I want to pass the inputs from a text file. There are two inputs, `a` and `b`, written line by line like this:

```
a    b
2   423
4    56.9
7   83.5
```

Now I want to call this txt file in a loop and pass each `a` and `b` value line by line so that the output of the C program is generated for each `a` and `b` value.

To do so I want to write a shell script which will call the txt file in read mode and after getting the data it will call the C program and then the C program will do the rest including the output.

As I am new to this shell scripting I am confused about how to open a text file and then read data line by line and store them in some variable in the shell script.

Please suggest how can I open the text file in read mode and then read data (which may not be always integers) and store them in some other variables.

Comment: why don't you read the txt file with your C program?

Comment: you can also try accessing the file directly from your C program using various file handling methods.

Comment: because  I am calling a pre- written  C program that and there is no provision to modify it as I have the access of exe file only.

So to incorporate this program in my program I want to run a shell script.

Comment: Can you add examples, based on the example file contents you already provided, how exactly your "C application" needs to be called?

Answer (score 13):

Assuming "inputs are given through command line" means that the program accepts command-line *arguments*, then you should be able to do this with `xargs`

Ex. given a minimal C program

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("Running %s\n", argv[0]);
  for(int i=1; i<argc; i++) printf("arg %d = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
  printf("\n");
}
```

compiled with `gcc -o someprog someprog.c`, and a file of whitespace-separated input arguments `inputs.txt`

```
$ cat inputs.txt 
2   423
4    56.9
7   83.5
```

Then

```
$ xargs -L1 ./someprog < inputs.txt
Running ./someprog
arg 1 = 2
arg 2 = 423

Running ./someprog
arg 1 = 4
arg 2 = 56.9

Running ./someprog
arg 1 = 7
arg 2 = 83.5
```

If your input file has a header, you will need to remove it (using `tail` for example).

---

If parallel processing would be computationally advantageous for your task, then you could do a similar thing with [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

```
parallel --colsep '[ \t]+' ./someprog {1} {2} :::: inputs.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple Bash example of such script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
tail -n +2 "input-file" | sort -u | while read -a args
do 
    echo "${args[0]}" "${args[1]}"
done
```

- The first command `tail -n +2 input-file` will output the content of the file `./input-file`, but without the first line. Here is assumed that the Bash script and the input file are in the same directory - `./` is the path to the current directory.
- This output will be piped `|` to the standard input of the command `sort` (with `-u` only the unique lines will be outputted), that will sort this input by the first column (use `man sort` to find out more options).
- The output of the command `sort -u` is piped to the STDIN of the `while-do-done` loop, where each line will be `read` as an array `-a`.
- Further the echo command will output the first and the second element of the array, named `args`. You should tweak this line - change `echo` with the path and the name of your C program.

The one line syntax of this example is:

```bsh
tail -n +2 "./input-file" | sort -u | while read -a ar; do echo "${ar[0]}" "${ar[1]}"; done
```

Another example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
INPUT_FILE="/path/to/input-file"
tail -n +2 "$INPUT_FILE" | sort -u | while read -a args
do 
    echo "${args[@]}"
done
```

- Here the name of the file `input-file` is changed with the variable `$INPUT_FILE`, which value is assigned preliminary.
- Also `echo "${args[@]}"` will output the whole content of the array `args` simultaneously.